# How to fix "ValueError: color kwarg must have one color per data set. 4 data sets and 1 colors were provided"?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, valueerror

I am trying to run the following code and getting
`ValueError: color kwarg must have one color per data set. 4 data sets and 1 colors were provided`
All my variables are of type Float32 and none of the rows contain an infinity value. I have only 1 df for creating this pairplot but python thinks that 4 datasets are provided. I don't know why. Any help on this issue is really appreciated. FYI: some of the variables in my df were of data type object converted to float using pd.to_numeric.

```
df_pairplot=df_4kmeans2[["Fraud_target",'sum_gmv','med_remember_me_code','sum_ff_address','sum_risky_ssn_login_tm','sum_purchase_as_dormant_buyer','sum_purhase_as_new_buyer','med_fm_segmentation_id','sumrisky_bsns_vrtcl_po','first_time_user','sum_bot_purchase','sum_gmv','med_paymentmethodtype_id','sum_risky_gmv_order','sum_risky_dist_ship_bill','med_categ_lvl2_id','avg_years_on_file','avg_time_of_the_day','avg_log_in_time_diff_sec','avg_dist_shipIP_sesnIP','avg_DIST_current_prev_sessn_IP','avg_shipping_billing_zip_mismatch']].apply(pd.to_numeric,downcast='float')

plt.title('Scatter Plots of all cleaned variables')
sns.pairplot(df_pairplot, plot_kws={'hue':df_pairplot["Fraud_target"],'alpha':0.9,'s':5})
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

`plt.scatter` (which is the function used to draw the off-diagonal axes) does not take a `hue` parameter. I'm guessing you are trying to do this:

```
sns.pairplot(df_pairplot, hue="Fraud_target", plot_kws={'alpha':0.9,'s':5})
```

Comment: I got an error when I added the hue argument inside the pairplot statement. Hence, I added the hue statement inside plot_kws